# Tkinter Quit button make exe not responding

Tags: python, tkinter

I create a window with Tkinter. When I click the quit button, windows shows the exe stop working. Could any one tell me why this happens? I think the problem is the self.quit, but I do not know the reason.

Here is the codes.

```
from Tkinter import *
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
    def createWidgets(self):
        self.Quit = Button(self, text = "QUIT", command = self.quit)
        self.Quit.pack(side = LEFT)

root = Tk()
app =App(master = root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I do not know if either of these will help, but you don't need `master = ` in the penultimate line, and try putting the command inside a lambda expression (lambda: self.quit). This has helped me with weird errors in the past.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: lambda is not necessary, and your statement about "weird errors" gives the impression that Tkinter is non-deterministic or flakey, which it's not. Lambda isn't magical and can't fix mysterious errors.

Comment: @BryanOakley It's not worth arguing about, but it did fix my errors. I'm not very experienced with Tkinter though. Also perfectly reliable software can still produce "weird errors" if you use it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the quit button, you are calling the `quit()` method of `Frame`. In its place, you need to call `destroy()` on the root element to finish the mainloop correctly.

```
self.Quit = Button(self, text = "QUIT", command = self.master.destroy)
```

Comment: Thank you, I add a root.destory() to finish the mainloop.